# How to wrap all occurances of known text inside an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, traversal

I want to find all TEXT or HREF matching a RegExp within an HMTL document and wrap those with a tag (e.g. turning plain text into links).

Consider the following HTML:

```html
<body>
  <!-- test1 <div>test2 <a href="test3">test4</a></div> -->
  test5
  <a href="test6">notest</a>
  <div>
    test8
    <p>
      test9 notest test10
      <a href="notest">test12</a>
      <input type="text" name="test13">test14</input>
    </p>
    test15
  </div>
</body>
```

Then this would be my required replacement:

```html
<body>
  <!-- test1 <div>test2 <a href="test3">test4</a></div> -->
  <div class="wrapped">test5</div>
  <div class="wrapped"><a href="test6">notest</a></div>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapped">test8</div>
    <p>
      <div class="wrapped">test9</div> notest
      <div class="wrapped">test10</div>
      <div class="wrapped"><a href="notest">test12</a></div>
      <input type="text" name="test13">test14</input>
    </p>
    <div class="wrapped">test15</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice that tests `5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15` got wrapped.

It is not acceptable to insert into input boxes or any other special HTML tags that are not displayed (e.g. `<script>` `<doctype>` and so on).

I was working with a stack principle before:

1. Push body onto stack.
2. `e = stack.pop()`.
3. Push all children of `e` of type element onto stack, except links (`<a>` nodes) and elements of `class="wrapped"`.
4. Check all remaining `e.children` of type link for a matching `href` or text and wrap.
5. Wrap all innermost matches within all `e.children` of type text.
6. If stack is not empty, then go to 2.
7. Complete

The JavaScript is only required to run on Firefox 8.

I would like to accomplish the wrappings without a tree traversal, linear would be optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not want any tree traversal? I think your current algorithm is as good as it gets.

The problem is that the DOM does not offer any sophisticated method to get all text nodes.

I didn't run any performance tests, but this one may have about the same speed:

1. `nodes := getElementsByTagName('*')`
2. `excludes := document.querySelectorAll('a, a *, .wrapped, .wrapped *, script, style, input, textarea [, ...]')`
   (`querySelectorAll` should perform pretty well)
3. `targets := nodes - excludes`
   (not sure about the performance here)
4. Iterate over `targets`

   - Iterate over children
   - Wrap each textNode
5. Handle `<a>` elements separately

Comment: What is so different about `<a>` elements that they would require special treatment? It's an inline element just like a `<p>` and a `<span>`.

Comment: The question requires a special treatment, since the href attribute should be searched.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck! I actually wrote something like this a while ago.

It may need some modification to get it to work with regexes, but that shouldn't be too hard.
The code has been tested in IE7,8,9, Chrome and Firefox

```
/*global window document addEvent*/

function textContent(node) {
    if (typeof node.textContent !== "undefined") {
        return node.textContent;
    } else {
        return node.nodeValue; // IE
    }
}
function setTextContent(node, new_value) {
    if (typeof node.textContent !== "undefined") {
        node.textContent = new_value;
    } else {
        node.nodeValue = new_value; // IE
    }
}

function replace_stuff(context_element) {
    var i = 0, node, pos, before, after, div;
    if (1 === context_element.nodeType) {
        for (; i < context_element.childNodes.length; i += 1) {
            replace_em(context_element.childNodes[i]);
        }
    } else if (3 === context_element.nodeType) {
        node = context_element;
        pos = textContent(node).indexOf("YOURSTRING"); // replace with regex if you so desire
        while (-1 !== pos) {
            before = textContent(node).substring(0, pos);
            after = textContent(node).substring(pos + 10, textContent(node).length);  // 10 is the lenth of YOURSTRING
            context_element.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(before), node);
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("YOURSTRING")); // reinsert original content
            context_element.parentNode.insertBefore(div, node);
            setTextContent(node, after);
            pos = textContent(node).indexOf("YOURSTRING"); // find next occurance
        }
    }
}

addEvent(window, "load", function () {  // you may need to change this line
    replace_stuff(document.getElementById("main"));
});
```

Basically it check the `textContent` of a node for YOURSTRING, splits up the text into two nodes: the text before YOURSTRING and the text after. It then wraps YOURSTRING in a div and inserts it in between the two other nodes.

Comment: Your example seems to be based on recursion. My guess is that this would cause many problems and a worse runtime performance than my current implementation.

Comment: The traversel method is hardly the problem here. Use a stack if you want to, I just find recursion more suitable for traversing trees. The hard part is splitting up your text nodes and inserting a new node.