# How to replace words appearing anywhere through the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have 2 arrays, one for old words and one for new ones:

```
old_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];
new_words = ['nword1', 'nword2', 'nword3'];
```

I need to find which words inside the DOM match any in the old_words array, replace it with the same index one in new_words, and wrap it in a  tag.
And yes, I know traversing the DOM is probably not the best option, but I don't know where the words might appear since it is meant to work on any website.
I can't figure out how to do this... this is what I have so far:

```
const regexp = new RegExp('(' + old_words.join('|') + ')', 'ig');
old_words.forEach(function (word, idx) {
    let addSpan = word.replace( regexp, `<span data-old-word="$&"> ${new_words[idx]}</span>`;
// that's all I have
});
```

the thing is, I don't know what to change to check the entire DOM as it fails...any tips would be appreciated...

I have previously attempted to do:

```
if (document.body.innerText.indexOf(word) !== -1){
//change
}
```

but it crashes because of the size. I assume I could take the values from the  only but still I'm unsure how to go about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803189/how-to-wrap-dom-keywords-in-a-span-tag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304089/how-to-wrap-all-occurances-of-known-text-inside-an-html-document

Answer (score -1):

if you start with an empty html and create the elements using createElement().

or if every element has a class you could do getElementByClass().